# jQuery AJAX Form Builder

Tags: ajax, forms, builder

I need some really stellar AJAX example forms.

I want to build simple but great 2 column forms with a dynamic form builder.

This is one example but want one that is very easy to use and that I can move rows up and down and is very flexible to code in.

Answer (score 3):

You may look into this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-builder-plugin/

Regards,

Chee Kin

P/S: I am the owner of the project

Comment: is this form allow radio button, checkbox and select box ??

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.formbuilder).